# Swift: CollectionView space

Tags: ios, swift

I have 12 cells in my `CollectionView`. I want to show 3 cells on one screen like this:

[image]

and scroll right to show another cells.

But now I create `CollectionView` and `CollectionViewCell` and edit cell in `storyboard` and I get this result:

[image]

How to fix it?

My code in `CollectionView`:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class MasterViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 12
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

        cell.label.text = String(indexPath.row)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        return cell
    }
}
```

My code in `CollectionViewCell`:

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: it is simple just make enable paging from storyboard after selecting UICollectionView

Comment: @Ravipanchal I select Scrolling enabled Paging enabled and Direction enabled. But space between 3 and 4 cells equals 10. And not 50.

Comment: So you have to define cell width according to screen like if screen size is 320 and space between two cell is 10 so you cell width will be 100 

Formula is like that 320(Screen width) - 20 (space between two cell) = 300 / 3 Cell in Screen  = 100 per cell

Comment: @Ravipanchal I need that space between screen and cell differed space between cell and cell. For example space between screen and cell 50 and space between cells 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that spacing you need to do like so

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 4
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}
```

so after each 3 cell in new section it will take that Section Inset and will give that space.

[image]

Comment: Thank You! It works. But is there no other way? I need that `numberOfSections return 1`.

Comment: no, you can use collectionView: `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int` but it's also for each section you can't manipulate for each row separately. so you have to divide it in section to vary the spacing for group of cells in section.

Comment: @user291334 if it does solved your problem accept as answered and close the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**I have added sample screen shot for your reference please check it 
and still you have confusion so please let me know**.[image]